# full outer join (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables  `Category`,`subcategory` and `product`

how can I do full outer join between these tables but on version 5.1.69 (mysql)

```
[category.cat_id] => category table l  
[subcategory.subcat_id] => subcategory tab1e 2  
[product.subcat_id] => product table 3
```

Comment: sorry [union] not work on version 5.1.69

Comment: you said that your version is: version 5.1.69 it already work there! check it again.. what is the error?

Attach your query and the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have cat_id as a foreign key in `Subcategory` table and `subcat_id` as a foreign key in `product` table.

here is an example inner join:

```
Select product_name,cat_name,subcat_name 
from Product p,Category c,Subcategory s 
where c.cat_id=s.cat_id and p.subcat_id=s.subcat_id and product_id=121
```